# Deleting an entity with concurrency in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to delete an entity in EF Core without loading it first from the database. I know similar questions have been asked before, but bear with me, because this case is different. Additional to the usual ID, the entity also has a row version, which is causing problems.

The entity is defined like this:

```
public int MyEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Other irrelevant properties
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

The entity is configured with the fluent API:

```
class MyEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity> {
    public void Configure( EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder ) {
        builder.Property( e => e.RowVersion )
            .IsRequired()
            .IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

The row version allows me to do optimistic concurrency checking. The problem is that when I try to delete the entity without loading it first like this...

```
void RemoveMyEntity( int id ) {
    MyEntity removeEntity = new MyEntity {
        Id = id
    };
    m_context.MyEntities.Attach( removeEntity );
    m_context.MyEntities.Remove( removeEntity );
}
```

...the concurrency check falls on my feet. I get this error message in a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

The reason is that EF Core generates this query to delete the item:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [MyEntity]
WHERE [Id] = @p57 AND [RowVersion] IS NULL;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT',N'@p57 int',@p57=1 -- <--The ID of the item to delete
```

The issue is clearly in `AND [RowVersion] IS NULL`. This condition can *never* be `true`, since (like I have clearly told EF when configuring the entity), the column is required and hence can not be `NULL`.

Of course, I have not added a row version in the entity I want to delete and I actually don't want to add the row version, because this would mean I have to get the data from the DB, which is not necessary in this case. I don't even mind concurrency checking here, because it does not hurt if the item was deleted before.

So the question is: Is there a way to ignore concurrency checking for this operation (but not for other operations in the same transaction) or to make the delete work in another way without having to get the row version from the DB first.

Comment: If you have the ID, why don't you have the rowversion too?

Comment: Because I get the ID from a foreign key (which is one of many reasons I could only have the ID).

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to disable it for a single operation. You probably have to run some ad-hoc SQL.

Comment: Why would be *enabled*, when it can never work?

Comment: Well, you tell EF to respect concurrency, so that's what it does. You *have* to query the row version, which can be done by a light query. Then assign it to `removeEntity`.

Comment: @GertArnold I might tell it to respect concurrency, but adding a condition to the query it should know can never be true doesn‘t do that.

Comment: That's just how optimistic concurrency control is implemented. You can change (update/delete) an entity if it wasn't changed between fetching it (even if that means: only getting the ID) and modifying it. Therefore this rowversion clause is added to each UPDATE and DELETE statement.

Comment: @GertArnold: As I wrote in the post, it worked in EF6. And if it is implemented like this I would consider it a bug. EF could choose to drop the condition in these cases or it could give me an error because I didn‘t provide the row version. But it shouldn‘t add an impossible condition. Not checking the value to compare a required column against seems like a quite naive implementation to me.

Comment: Issues for EF Core go here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues, but arguably-correct behavior that differs from EF 6 might not get changed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Thanks for the info. I will add one.

Comment: That would mean it would also succeed if you forget to populate the rowversion property, for example by not bringing it back from a UI operation. I understand why EF implemented it this way. And I just checked:  EF6 did the same thing.

Comment: @GertArnold: it should give me a different error at least because a) I react to concurrency errors by fixing the data and this is not a case for that and b) It took me quite a while to find out what‘s wrong. A different error could have told me in the face. Anyway, I will correct the EF6 part of my post.

Comment: By adding the row version, you are forcing yourself to load the data from the database if you want to *update* it, i.e. you cannot use the "typical" forced update. And if you are forced to load it for updating, what's the problem of loading it for deletion? I doubt you do so many deletes in order to have that so critical. Not that I'm advocating EFC, but they have enough more important issues/bugs for solving.

Comment: As others have well pointed out, the where clause is necessary. The only missing piece "should give different error", the exception message states clearly that data may have changed or modified. You could easily see the logs to find out which query is being run and arrive at the conclusion that RowVersion is missing. As for the ability to ignore it see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6218

Comment: @smit: I *have* profiled the query, but that‘s not the main point. The reaction to a concurrency issue is fundamentally different than to a DB error. Since a concurrency exception can happen any time when the DB has changed you write code to resync the data. But that is not the case here. The data has not changed. EF is adding a condition to the query *it should know can never be true*. It then falsely interprets the result as an optimistic concurrency issue. Throwing a concurrency exception here will invoke the resync error handler when it actually should crash hard.

Comment: There are plenty of ways users can write a buggy code. Try to identity all the cases and providing users a pretty message is complex task and provides little value. The only difference in this case from the case where user provided incorrect value is, EF Core can perform a null check. If such checks are added then performance would drop drastically while the update is going to fail on database anyway.

Comment: @smit: It‘s not about the message, it‘s about the exception type that will trigger a different error handler (there is an entire topic in MSDN on how to handle optimistic concurrency exceptions). Anyway, I will save myself the effort to open an issue.

Comment: @Smit: Just for the record, I don‘t buy the *drastic performance drop* here. We‘re talking about a simple null check. How would that affect performance drastically?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about EF Core but I use the following workaround for EF 6: I have created additional NoConcurencyDbContext which inherits from the main, override OnModelCreating and configure all RowVersion properties to ConcurencyMode.None

```
publicclass NoConcurencyDbContext : MainDbContext {

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityWithRowVersio>().Property(t => t.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken(false);

    }
}
```

You can write T4 template and generate such context automatically from EF model.
So the idea is simple modify model configuration whithin child dbcontext for particular operation. **Hope it can be done in EF Core as well**

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the following pattern that I paste and explain below.

1) You must have a row version field defined on your model and database.

2) For deletion, just supply the id and the row version of entity you already has retrieved when you displayed it for edit update or delete, you must have at least the id.

3) If you don't have row version, don't care, it will defaulted to null.

The pattern goes as follows:

a) Checks if the entity is tracked on the change tracker, and if yes, it just delete it.

b) If the entity is not tracked, then it mocks a new fake entity with the id and the row version you have (or null).

c) Aha! you do not have provide a row version, then **forcefully** you must supply a valid one from the database, go to the database a pick one (use dbset Find() method or..).

(on my case I am using a scalar t-sql function, executed from withing the db context to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0).

d ) Finally it assert that the deletion has succeed returning true
(later on.. when calling save changes the dbcontext will persist the changes or explode!!!, is up to you to handle the errors)

I will paste some code from a generic repository:

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteByIdAsync(TKey id, byte[] rowVersion = null, CancellationToken? token = null) 
{
    var entityTracked = _context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<TEntity>()
        .Select((EntityEntry e) => (TEntity)e.Entity)
        .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(id));                                                             

    if (entityTracked != null)                                                                         
    {
        _context.Remove(entityTracked);                                                                     // If entity is tracked just delete it
    }
    else                                                                                                    // If not tracked, just mock up a new entity.
    {
        var entityMocked = new TEntity { Id = id, RowVersion = rowVersion };                                // (*) ValidateModelContext extension custom code will not validate for EntityState.Deleted to avoid moked entity fail validations. We are going to delete it anyway so has no sense to validate it before deleting it.

        if (rowVersion == null)                                                                             // DUDE!! Why you do not pass me a valid row version?. Then I forcelly must do a database trip to get the rowversion for this id. We do it executing an scalar function that returns me current row version value for this entity. 
            entityMocked.RowVersion = await GetRowVersionAsync(id.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);        // If the record do not exist on the database a null is returned. In such case, even if we already know that something went wrong, we let the dbconcurrency error occurs when saving changes since is really a concurency error, since the record not longer exists.

        _context.Remove(entityMocked);                                                                      // Just delete it it.
    }

    return true;
}
```

The t-sql is like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDepartmentRowVersion] (@Id INT) RETURNS BINARY(8) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @rowVersion AS BINARY(8)
IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM Department ELSE SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM Department WHERE Id = @Id
RETURN @rowVersion
END
GO
```

The code on the db context for mapping those udfs are like:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetRowVersionAsync<TEntity>(string id = null)
{
    switch (typeof(TEntity))
    {
        case var type when type == typeof(Department):
            return await Department.Select(e => GetDepartmentRowVersion(Convert.ToInt32(id))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        case var type when type == typeof(Player):
            return await (id == null ? Player.Select(e => GetPlayerRowVersion(Guid.Empty)) : Player.Select(e => GetPlayerRowVersion(new Guid(id)))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        case var type when type == typeof(Address):
            return await (id == null ? Address.Select(e => GetAddressRowVersion(Guid.Empty)) : Address.Select(e => GetAddressRowVersion(new Guid(id)))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        default:
            return new byte[] { };
    }
}

public static byte[] GetPlayerRowVersion(Guid id) => null;     // Scalar function mappings.
public static byte[] GetAddressRowVersion(Guid id) => null;    // When using an in memory database since SQL UDF functions are not mapped to any Server, so we return a null value instead of throwing an error.
public static byte[] GetDepartmentRowVersion(int id) => null;
```

You could build specific migrations to update the ufs like so:

```
    [DbContext(typeof(DataContext))]
    [Migration(nameof(DataContext) + nameof(GetDepartmentRowVersion))]
    public class GetDepartmentRowVersion : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder builder)
        {
            var sp = $@"
CREATE FUNCTION {nameof(DataContext.GetDepartmentRowVersion)} (@Id INT) RETURNS BINARY(8) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @rowVersion AS BINARY(8)
IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([{nameof(Department.RowVersion)}]) FROM {nameof(DataContext.Department)} ELSE SELECT @rowVersion = [{nameof(Department.RowVersion)}] FROM {nameof(DataContext.Department)} WHERE {nameof(Department.Id)} = @Id
RETURN @rowVersion
END";

            if (builder.ActiveProvider.Split('.').Last() == StorageProvider.SqlServer.ToString()) builder.Sql(sp);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder builder)
        {
            var sp = $@"IF OBJECT_ID('{nameof(DataContext.GetDepartmentRowVersion)}') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION {nameof(DataContext.GetDepartmentRowVersion)}";

            if (builder.ActiveProvider.Split('.').Last() == StorageProvider.SqlServer.ToString()) builder.Sql(sp);
        }
    }
```

I hope you keep the key concepts.. BR and happy codding